# Installing Visual Studio 2003 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows, error-handling, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-2003, frontpage-extensions

My team is currently supporting a 1.1 app and we are installing VS.NET 2003 on Windows 7.  We haven't had any issues on the 32-bit machines, but FrontPage Server Extensions are failing to install on my 64-bit machine.

Others say that they have done this successfully, so I wanted to know if anyone here has and if they know of a solution.

The specific issue is that FPSE (to clarify, I'm installing "FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions for IIS 7.0") fails to install correctly.  In EventViewer I get the error:

> Microsoft FrontPage Server Extensions:
>
> Error #3004f Message: Unable to read configuration information for Microsoft Internet Information Server: ImpersonateLoggedOnUser Error.

I've looked for errors with ImpersonateLoggedOnUser on 64-bit and did find a case where it fails on 64-bit when UAC is turned off (which I did have it off).  I turned UAC back on, ran command prompt as administrator, and ran msiexec on the FPSE package.  Still no dice.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://frankbuchan.blogspot.com/2009/08/visual-studio-2003-under-windows-7.html) (and the others it points to) for installing.

Comment: Could it be something to do with running IIS in 32bit mode...?

Comment: I gave up on this after wasting a few days on it (more than I should have).  I've just bit the bullet and will continue developing this product over Remote Desktop on my old XP dev machine until we can finally port the product.

Comment: Do you actually need the Frontpage stuff? Otherwise: `N:\setup\setup.exe /NO_BSLN_CHECK`, where N: is the drive of the CD/DVD

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install Visual Studio 2003 on a virtual Windows 7 (64 bit) by

1. Installing [RTR FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions for IIS 7.5](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/frontpage-server-extensions/installing-the-frontpage-server-extensions-on-iis).
2. Letting the installer for VS2003 install the prerequisites.
3. Continue installation of VS2003.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try [Visual Studio .NET 2003 and Windows 7 can get along – Seriously](http://technikhil.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/visual-studio-2003-and-windows-7-can-get-along-really/):

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need FPSE (or some other part of the setup) you can always install VS without it.
to do so find the file "baseline.dat" in your setup folder, open it with notepad and delete the component.

this should work for visual studio version from 98 up to 2010,
for 2013 microsoft has changed it.

the baseline.dat is pretty self explanatory, but if you need any more help please post the file here.